# Domain AD users aren't get discovered after adding Ubuntu under AD domain control

Tags: authentication, ldap, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I've Joined a my ad domain with my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS VM (I followed [this doc](https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain/)) and I'veJoined the AD domain with Ubuntu as

```
sudo realm join -U Administrator win2016.local
```

`realm  list` show below output

```
WIN2016.local
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: WIN2016.LOCAL
  domain-name: win2016.local
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@win2016.local
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins: swapnil@win2016.local
  permitted-groups:
```

But, when I try to discover any AD user as below

1. id swapnil@WIN2016.local OR
2. id swapnil@win2016.local OR
3. id swapnil

It always show error as `id: ‘swapnil@WIN2016.local’: no such user`.. What I'm missing here?

Note: on my `win2016.local` AD server , `swapnil` user is present

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to issue the command realm permit --all?

this worked for me, however, I still can not log in to a desktop with an AD user.